# psycopg stops deserializing in celery app context

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, celery-task, psycopg3

I have a psycopg `ConnectionPool` that extends the flask app:

```py
def init_pool(cfg, connection_class, name) -> ConnectionPool:

    pool = ConnectionPool(
        conninfo=f"postgresql://{cfg['user']}:{cfg['password']}@{cfg['host']}/{cfg['database']}",
        min_size=cfg['min_pool_size'],
        max_size=cfg['max_pool_size'],
        connection_class=connection_class,
        kwargs={"autocommit": True, "options": "-c idle_session_timeout=0"},
        name=name
    )
    pool.wait(timeout=30.0)

    with pool.connection() as conn:
        # retrieve a connection to register the user-defined types
        # in the global scope of the application (*default*)
        register_composite_types(conn)


    return pool

def register_composite_types(conn):
    """ Convert postgresql type -> python
        * Register the shared composite types in the conn scope.
        * Utilizes the built-in psycopg factory call
    """
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        for (t,) in cur.execute("select shared_types()"):
            if not conn.broken:
                info = CompositeInfo.fetch(conn, t)
                register_composite(info, context=None)
            else:
                raise LevelsDbException(project_id=None, filename=None,
                                        message="Failed to initialize: Broken connection")
```

I'm using a custom task class that injects the flask app context (per the latest documentation for [flask+celery](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/celery/)):

```py
def celery_init(app: Flask) -> Celery:

    class FlaskTask(Task):
        def __call__(self, *args: object, **kwargs: object) -> object:
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    # instantiated once for each task.  Each task serves multiple task requests.
    celery_app = Celery(app.name, task_cls=FlaskTask)
    celery_app.config_from_object(celeryconfig)
    celery_app.set_default()
    app.extensions["celery"] = celery_app

    return celery_app
```

I have a `shared_task` that uses the pool by way of the flask proxy, `current_app`:

```py
with current_app.inspection_db_pool.connection() as conn:
    field_data = db.get_file_fields( conn
                                   , project_id
                                   , path
                                   , hashstr
                                   )

# field_data (a Cursor returned from `conn.execute`)
fields: list[dict] = fields_from_levels_db(field_data)

# ... 
def fields_from_levels_db(file_fields: Iterable) -> list[dict]:
    """ file_fields is a Cursor """
    return [ dict(
        idx = field.field_idx,
        purpose = field.purpose,
        ...
        levels = field.levels

    ) for (field,) in file_fields ]
```

The `shared_task` function worked as intended in the flask app.  However, as a celery worker configured using the `FlaskTask`, I get the following error (`field_idx` is supposed to be a dict key):

```py
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'field_idx'
```

My troubleshooting efforts included referencing the pool by way of `self.flask_app.inspection_pool`.  I got the same error.

Generally speaking, this type of error occurs when the postgresql user-types are not registered and/or available in the current scope.  Am I properly registering the user-types in the relevant scope?

Answer (score 0):

Relying on the global scope to maintain the initialized adapters fails in the celery context.

To make sure that each connection in the pool has a valid reference to the adapters, I used the `ConnectionPool` `configure` setting.  The setting is a callback that mutates the connection prior to making it available in the pool. The callback includes a call to `psycopg.types.composite.register_composite` with `context=conn`.

```py
def init_inspection_pool(cfg) -> ConnectionPool:
    def configure(conn: psycopg.Connection):
        register_composite_types(conn, context=conn)
        with_features(conn)

    return init_pool(cfg, InspectionConnection, 'inspection_pool',
                     configure=configure)
```

Another approach that seemed promising was to exploit the use of an optional class that inherits from `Connection`.  This was a dead-end for this purpose.  I include a custom class only to differentiate the pool from others in the app.